# decode base64 svg data to a svg file

Tags: linux, svg, base64, decode, data-uri

I have a file containing a svg image which is base64 encoded (data-uri). The file starts with

data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN....

How to decode this to a .svg file in linux ?

Answer (score 47):

You can copy/paste the string (`data:image` etc. included) in the url bar of a modern browser; it will decrypt it for you. Then you can simply save the page as an svg.

Comment: thumbs up for the copy/paste in browser url bar.

Comment: Instead of saving, one can also directly inspect with the browser developer tools.

Answer (score 7):

You could use an online base64 decoder, such as http://www.base64decode.org/

Answer (score 7):

To address the OP question:

> How to decode this to a .svg file in linux ?

Since linux has python by default, I suggest to use python script.

Here is a working example:

```
import base64 

#change "YOURFILE" with the name of your original file
with open("YOURFILE", "rb") as f: encoded = f.read()

encoded = encoded.replace("data:image/svg+xml;base64,", "")
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)

#change "NEWFILE" with the name that you want to give your new svg 
with open("NEWFILE.svg", "wb") as f: f.write(decoded)
```

If you are new to python, simply copy-paste the code above into a file with `.py` extension, for example `aaabbb.py` and then execute it like this:

```
python aaabbb.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g `base64 --decode < "your base64 data here"`. And you probably need to strip off the `data:image/svg+xml;base64,` part before passing it in.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use the online tool 
http://www.hosting4free.info/Base64Decode/Base64-Decode.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I use SVG online decoder, fast and simple
https://base64.online/decoders/decode-base64-to-svg

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem:

> let **url** = 'PHN2ZyBpZD0iTGF5ZXJfMM...'
>
> var svg = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(**url**)));